# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page at Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Tags: mysql, jsp, jdbc

**type** Exception report

**message** An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line 5

**description** The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at       line 5

```
5:     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

6:     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root", "harsha");

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Do I need to install any mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar  I have downloaded but not understanding where to place that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because of your JDBC driver was not in your class path..

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Basically you are trying to create an object of a class which is not loaded into JVM...Solution is place your JDBC driver jar into your class path.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try place the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar`
in your webapp's `/web-inf/lib` directory

and then, restart or redeploy